Looking for a test on the quality of an approximated CDF
I have a $C^1$ function, $\mathcal{E}_n(x)$ that stands as an approximation of a CDF, $F(x)$ of a continuous random variable $X$, derived using $n$ sampled points, $X_1,X_2,...,X_n \sim f$. The PDF, $f$, is not well defined, meaning $F(x) = \int_I f(x)dx$ is not something achievable, hence why we have $\mathcal{E}_n(x)$. The approximation is, in fact, a monotonic interpolation of the points in the empirical distribution function $F_n(x)$, such that $F_n(X_i) = \mathcal{E}_n(X_i)$, and $F_n(x)<\mathcal{E}_n(x)$ for $X_{i-1} < x < X_{i}$. I can quantify the "quality" of $F_n$ using DKW bounds, but what I'd prefer is to quantify the quality of $\mathcal{E}_n$ directly. Is there a way I can put confidence bounds around $\mathcal{E}_n$ directly? I currently just have the DKW bounds around $\mathcal{E}_n$, which is fine, but I was hoping for bounds that would be $C^1$, matching that of $\mathcal{E}_n$. I don't have very robust knowledge of other confidence bounds, but from what I've seen they all are step-like functions matching that of the ECDF. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

This is all very abstract, can you tell us the context this occurs? Please do so by editing the post, not only as comments, as comments are easily overseen and can be deleted!
